# How to show directory page conditionally on InstallOption?

Tags: nsis

I am using the MUI user interface, but only want to show the directory page when the user selects a certain CheckBox in an InstallOption page.

My problem is that I don't know how to conditionally disable the MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY page.

```
Function InstallTypeLeave
  !insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $INSTALL_TYPE "InstallType.ini" "Field 1" "State"
  SetShellVarContext current
  StrCmp $INSTALL_TYPE "1" SET_LOCATION_LOCAL SET_LOCATION_NETWORK
  SET_LOCATION_LOCAL:
    StrCpy $INSTDIR "$APPDATA\..."
    GOTO SET_LOCATION_FINISH
  SET_LOCATION_NETWORK:
    StrCpy $INSTDIR ""
    GOTO SET_LOCATION_FINISH
  SET_LOCATION_FINISH:
FunctionEnd

; Directory page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
```

The page should only be shown when `$INSTALL_TYPE` is not `"1"`, how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a page callback that discards the page depending on your condition, e.g:

```
#specify a callback before the MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW DirectoryPageCallBack
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

#...

Function DirectoryPageCallBack
    ${if} $INSTALL_TYPE = 1
        Abort    #in pre-function callback, discard the page
    ${endif}
FunctionEnd
```

See the [Callbacks](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.5.3) reference for details.